# Commenting a block of code containing a comment block uncomments the comments

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

Sorry about the title, but the issue I have is for example the following

```
var someArray = []

/**
 * Some comment
 * on
 * multiple
 * lines
 */

forEach(someArray, function(stuff) {
    return stuff
})
```

Now let's say I want to comment that whole code block. I will highlight all of that and use ctrl + /. Well, in Sublime the results will be:

```
var someArray = []

*
 * Some comment
 * on
 * multiple
 * lines


forEach(someArray, function(stuff) {
    return stuff
})
```

For some reason the comment block with asterisk is messing up the way Sublime does commenting.

I wanted the expected results to be:

```
// var someArray = []

// /**
//  * Some comment here
//  * on
//  * multiple
//  * lines
//  */

// forEach(someArray, function(stuff) {
//     return stuff
// })
```

Anyway I can fix this? It's hard to comment big blocks of code if the comment block is in the middle of it.

I am on Sublime3 Build 3114.

Comment: I only get the undesirable results you show, when I highlight only the /** */ comment block by itself and hit Ctrl+/   When I highlight the block comment and some text, I get the behaviour you want

Comment: I know what you mean. I happened to give a very poor example. I updated the original sample code. If there are multiple lines in a comment block it won't work. I tested it in Sublime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens for me too. You may want to report the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core). Until they fix it, here's a workaround:

1. Highlight code block.
2. Hit `ctrl+shift+l`. I don't know what the equivalent would be in OSX, but if you open your default keybindings, you can find it by searching for `"split_selection_into_lines"`. This creates a cursor on each line you highlighted.
3. The cursors start at the end of the line. Hit `Home` twice to get all cursors to the beginning of the line (again, I don't know the OSX equivalent).
4. Type in your comments: `//`.

Comment: This is a very good workaround and you just taught me a shortcut command that I didn't know about. I'll also report the issue.